# strace got message --- SIGIO (I/O possible) @ 0 (0) ---

Tags: strace

I'm trying to monitor serial port communication using `strace -s9999 -o serialtrace.log -eread,write,ioctl` command. After few normal logging messages I got guge amount of message `--- SIGIO (I/O possible) @ 0 (0) ---`. What does it means? How to get normal information instead of these lines?

Answer (score 2):

If the application is receiving `SIGIO` signals, it means the application has placed at least one file descriptor into asynchronous mode, for example by doing `fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FASYNC)`.

If you don't want `strace` to report those signals, add the option `-e 'signal=!SIGIO'`. (You'll need those single quotes to quote the `'!'` in most shells.) From the [strace man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace):

```
-e signal=set
    Trace only the specified subset of signals. The default is signal=all.
    For example, signal=!SIGIO (or signal=!io) causes SIGIO signals
    not to be traced.
```

Comment: but I have a lot of  SIGIO messages and no read/write/ioctl ones. And I know that programm still reads/writes to files

Comment: You ought to be seeing read, write, and ioctl lines. The command line you gave works OK for me on debian. If you run this same strace command on a more conventional command, such as `ls`, do you get any read, write, and ioctl lines?